# Does npm-force-resolutions break the sync between package.json and package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

This is my `package.json`.

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    ...
  }
```

After deleting `node_modules` `package-lock.json`, I tried `npm install`.

When `npm install` finished, I deleted `node_modules` again and tried `npm ci`.

Then, this error messages showed up.

```
'npm ci' can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync.
Please update your lock file with 'npm install' before continuing.
```

I erased `resolutions` and `scripts.preinstall` in `package.json` and tried it again exactly same.

Then, error messages didn't show up.

So, I'm guessing `npm-force-resolutions` breaks the sync between `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same thing happened to me after moving the node js from v12 to v16,what is the npm version you are using? if it's above 8.3 , you can use overrides https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides